# How do I fix this sidebar for mobile?

Tags: html, css

My websites sidebar doesn't work on mobile. If you wanna see what i mean, go to [Zinexium](https://ykmmorgan.github.io/ZinexiumRBLX/developers.html). I don't know what to do, im new to html. [The code.](https://github.com/YkmMorgan/ZinexiumRBLX/blob/main/developers.html)

Thank you!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sidebar.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sidebarStyle.css" type="text/css" />
    <meta name="description" content="Developers of Zinexium." />
        <title>Zinexium</title>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.materialdesignicons.com/4.9.95/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <aside class="sidebar">
      <nav>
        <ul class="sidebar__nav">
          <li>
            <a href="index.html" class="sidebar__nav__link">
              <i class="mdi mdi-home"></i>
              <span class="sidebar__nav__text">Home</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="developers.html" class="sidebar__nav__link">
              <i class="mdi mdi-account-multiple"></i>
              <span class="sidebar__nav__text">Developers</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="download.html" class="sidebar__nav__link">
              <i class="mdi mdi-download"></i>
              <span class="sidebar__nav__text">Download</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="contact.html" class="sidebar__nav__link">
              <i class="mdi mdi-phone"></i>
              <span class="sidebar__nav__text">Contact</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="about.html" class="sidebar__nav__link">
              <i class="mdi mdi-tooltip-text"></i>
              <span class="sidebar__nav__text">About</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
                        <a href="logs.html" class="sidebar__nav__link">
                            <i class="mdi mdi-message-alert"></i>
                            <span class="sidebar__nav__text">Logs</span>
          </a>
                    </li>
           <li>
   <a href="https://discord.gg/QTkncurCkm" target="_blank" class="sidebar__nav__link">
     <i class="mdi mdi-discord"></i>
     <span class="sidebar__nav__text">Discord</span>
   </a>
</li>
          
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </aside>
    <div class="about-section">
      <h1>Developers</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="main">
        <h2 style="text-align: center">Our Team</h2>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
              <img src="Morgan.jpeg" alt="Morgan" style="width: 100%" />
              <div class="container">
                <h2>MorganInnit</h2>
                <p class="title">Founder & Main Dev</p>
                <p>i wanna die.</p>
                <p>
                  morgan#0887<br />
                  UserID:780879021935689799
                </p>
                <p>
                  <a href="http://dsc.bio/morganoutit" target="_blank"
                    ><button class="button">Contact</button></a
                  >
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
              <img src="thonk.jpeg" alt="ThonkPT" style="width: 100%" />
              <div class="container">
                <h2>ThonkPT</h2>
                <p class="title">Co Dev</p>
                <p>kewl gamer.</p>
                <p>
                  ThonkPT#3766<br />
                  UserID:710220284531310734
                </p>
                <p>
                  <a href="http://dsc.bio/thonkpt2" target="_blank"
                    ><button class="button">Contact</button></a
                  >
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--end of row-->
      </div>
      <!--end of main-->
    </div>
    <!--end of wrapper-->
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
:root {
  --sidebar-width: 4.5em;
}

.sidebar {
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    transition: width 0.2s ease;
}

.sidebar nav {
    height: 100%;
}

.sidebar .sidebar__nav {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.sidebar .sidebar__nav .sidebar__nav__link {
    align-items: center;
    color: #bbb;
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color 0.2s ease, background-color 0.2s ease;
}

.sidebar .sidebar__nav .sidebar__nav__link:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    color: #80f;
}

.sidebar .sidebar__nav .sidebar__nav__text {
    display: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.sidebar .sidebar__nav i {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

@media (max-width: 572px) {
    .sidebar {
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .sidebar .sidebar__nav {
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .sidebar .sidebar__nav .sidebar__nav__link {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0.75em;
    }

    .sidebar .sidebar__nav i {
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 572px) {
    .sidebar {
        height: 100vh;
        left: 0;
        width: var(--sidebar-width);
    }

    .sidebar:hover {
        width: 14rem;
    }

    .sidebar .sidebar__nav {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    

    .sidebar .sidebar__nav .sidebar__nav__link {
        padding: 1em;
    }

    .sidebar:hover .sidebar__nav .sidebar__nav__text {
        display: inline;
    }

    .sidebar .sidebar__nav i {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
    }
}

@media (max-height: 434px) {
    .sidebar {
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
}

:root {
  --sidebar-width: 4.5em;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}

* {
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 992px;
  padding: 2em 1.5em;
}

.main h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.main p {
  color: #444;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  line-height: 2;
  text-align: justify;
}

@media (min-width: 572px) {
  .main {
    margin-left: var(--sidebar-width);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .main {
    padding: 2.5em;
  }
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
p {
  font-size: 34px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  /* height: 200px; */
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
.main {
  margin: auto;
}
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  margin: 4em;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.card {
  width: 400px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
} 
.card p {
  font-size: 150%; /* changes font size inside of cards*/
}

.about-section {
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #474e5d;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  padding: 0 16px;
}
.container::after,
.row::after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
.title {
  color: grey;
}

.button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
}

.rainbow {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: monospace;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}
.rainbow_text_animated {
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    #6666ff,
    #0099ff,
    #00ff00,
    #ff3399,
    #6666ff
  );
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  animation: rainbow_animation 6s ease-in-out infinite;
  background-size: 400% 100%;
}

@keyframes rainbow_animation {
  0%,
  100% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }

  50% {
    background-position: 100% 0;
  }
}

#rcorners1 {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 345px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sidebar.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sidebarStyle.css" type="text/css" />
    <meta name="description" content="Developers of Zinexium." />
        <title>Zinexium</title>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.materialdesignicons.com/4.9.95/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <aside class="sidebar">
      <nav>
        <ul class="sidebar__nav">
          <li>
            <a href="index.html" class="sidebar__nav__link">
              <i class="mdi mdi-home"></i>
              <span class="sidebar__nav__text">Home</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="developers.html" class="sidebar__nav__link">
              <i class="mdi mdi-account-multiple"></i>
              <span class="sidebar__nav__text">Developers</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="download.html" class="sidebar__nav__link">
              <i class="mdi mdi-download"></i>
              <span class="sidebar__nav__text">Download</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="contact.html" class="sidebar__nav__link">
              <i class="mdi mdi-phone"></i>
              <span class="sidebar__nav__text">Contact</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="about.html" class="sidebar__nav__link">
              <i class="mdi mdi-tooltip-text"></i>
              <span class="sidebar__nav__text">About</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
                        <a href="logs.html" class="sidebar__nav__link">
                            <i class="mdi mdi-message-alert"></i>
                            <span class="sidebar__nav__text">Logs</span>
          </a>
                    </li>
           <li>
   <a href="https://discord.gg/QTkncurCkm" target="_blank" class="sidebar__nav__link">
     <i class="mdi mdi-discord"></i>
     <span class="sidebar__nav__text">Discord</span>
   </a>
</li>
          
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </aside>
    <div class="about-section">
      <h1>Developers</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="main">
        <h2 style="text-align: center">Our Team</h2>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
              <img src="Morgan.jpeg" alt="Morgan" style="width: 100%" />
              <div class="container">
                <h2>MorganInnit</h2>
                <p class="title">Founder & Main Dev</p>
                <p>i wanna die.</p>
                <p>
                  morgan#0887<br />
                  UserID:780879021935689799
                </p>
                <p>
                  <a href="http://dsc.bio/morganoutit" target="_blank"
                    ><button class="button">Contact</button></a
                  >
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
              <img src="thonk.jpeg" alt="ThonkPT" style="width: 100%" />
              <div class="container">
                <h2>ThonkPT</h2>
                <p class="title">Co Dev</p>
                <p>kewl gamer.</p>
                <p>
                  ThonkPT#3766<br />
                  UserID:710220284531310734
                </p>
                <p>
                  <a href="http://dsc.bio/thonkpt2" target="_blank"
                    ><button class="button">Contact</button></a
                  >
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--end of row-->
      </div>
      <!--end of main-->
    </div>
    <!--end of wrapper-->
  </body>
</html>
```

The snippet isn't the exact website, only the developers page. If you wanna see the actual page, go to "The code" i linked.
Thanks.
P.S. The snippet is missing some things, so go to the actual developers page if you wanna see it ig.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please edit your question to contain a minimal reproduciable code snippet and a cklear question. `Something isnt working` is not helpfull as a description. PS: A code to a fiddle still needs to contain a minimal reproduciable code snippet here.

Comment: ill try.  15 chars

Comment: is that good?  i tried my best lel

Comment: “doesn't work” [is not a question we can answer](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "doesn't work" you meant "is hiding under the content" ...the solution is to give it the `z-index: 1` in your CSS:

```
.sidebar {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

it will do the job.